# How do you get inferred type from a typescript AST?

Tags: typescript, abstract-syntax-tree, typescript1.6, typescript1.7

I'm using the built-in parser to generate the AST from source code:

```
const ts = require('typescript')
//...
const ast = ts.createSourceFile(filename, fs.readFileSync(filename).toString(), ts.ScriptTarget.ES6, true)
```

Is there a way to get the inferred type of a variable from the AST? For example, in the code below, `bar` is of type `IBar`. The compiler knows about that type---`bar.foo()` doesn't compile---how can I programmatically get the type?

```
interface IBar { bar() } 
const foo : IBar = //...
export const bar = foo
```

Answer (score 5):

> The compiler knows about that type---bar.foo() doesn't compile---how can I programmatically get the type?

The `AST` is not the *complete* story for TypeChecking. You need a `TypeChecker`.

The simplest solution is to create a program (some docs https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/compiler/program.html) and then use `program.getTypeChecker` (more docs https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/compiler/checker.html)

Comment: added details in my answer. Care to add anything?

Comment: Sadly, this answer is why link-type answers are recommended against :(

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell this does the trick:

```
// load typechecker for file
const program = ts.createProgram([filename], {});
const typeChecker = program.getTypeChecker()
// now get ast
const ast = ts.createSourceFile(filename, filecontents, ts.ScriptTarget.ES6, true))
// get node under question using ts.forEachChild (not shown here)
const node = // ...

const type = typeChecker.getTypeAtLocation(node);
```

The only weird part is that in a variable declaration, the "node" must be the `value` (aka FirstLiteralToken) and not the `label` (aka Identifier)---otherwise, the type is undefined.
For example, if the file contents are `const foo = 123`, passing the node for "foo" to typeChecker#getTypeAtLocation won't work. You must pass the node for "123"

Comment: This doens't solve the problem posed in the question...almost