# How can I get the inferred type using TypeScripts compiler API?

Tags: typescript

I'm writing a TS language server plugin and need to get the inferred type for an object literal:

```js
const x: TypeA = {};
```

I have a `Node` for the opening brace by using:

```js
const node = (ts2 as any).getTouchingToken(fileSrc, m.index);
if(ts.isObjectLiteralExpression(node.parent)) {
    const t = checker.getTypeAtLocation(node.parent);
    // "escapedName": "__object"
    // Want to get the inferred type, and also all properties of that type.
}
```

This question answers for primitive types:
[How do you get inferred type from a typescript AST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34736109/how-do-you-get-inferred-type-from-a-typescript-ast)